# How to fix "{"name":"error","attributes":{"message":"Exception happens in the Test Runner." in VS code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, testng

I have installed Java Language support extension and have imported TestNG jar but on running the Test in VS code the following error is printed in Java Test Runner console

```
 {"name":"error","attributes":{"message":"Exception happens in the Test Runner.","trace":"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.testng.TestNGRunner.run(TestNGRunner.java:33)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.testng.TestNGLauncher.execute(TestNGLauncher.java:32)
    at com.microsoft.java.test.runner.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
"}}.
```

I have tried checking the launch.json and I have also tried reinstalling extension but nothing works.

```
public class Test_2 {
    @Test
    void setup()
    {
        System.out.println("Setup");
    }
}
```

Comment: `com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException` - add the jar that contains this class to your classpath

Comment: have you add the jar path to classpath,refer to [add jar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_adding-external-jar).

Comment: Yes, even that doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to inlcude the jcommander jar in your build path,for maven like:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.beust/jcommander -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
  <version>1.27</version>
</dependency>
```

check if the version of your lib actually contains the missing class " com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException",if its not present try a different version of the lib.